# Auditing using Data tables vs Separate Audit tables

Tags: java, jpa, database-design, entity, audit

I am in the process of designing a new java application which has very strict requirements for auditing. A brief context is here:

I have a complex entity with multiple one to many nested relationships. If any of the field changes, I need to consider it as a new version of the object and all this need to be audited as well. Now I have two options:

1.) Do not do any update operation, just insert a new entity whenever anything changes. This would require me to create all the relational objects (even if they have not been changed) as I do not want to hold references to any previous version objects. My data tables becomes my auditing table as well.

OR

2.) Always do an update operation and maintain the auditing information in separate tables. That would add some more complexity in terms of implementation.

I would like to know if there is a good vs bad practice for any of these two approaches.

Thanks,
-csn

Comment: You could use Hibernate Envers that will do the second option automatically.

Answer (score 2):

What should define your choice is your insert/update/read patterns for both the "live" data and the audits.

Most commonly these pattern are very different for both kinds. 

- Conserning "live" it depends a lot on your application but I can imagine you have significants inserts; significatant updates; lot of reads. Live data also require transactionality and have lot relationship between tables for which you need to keep consistency. They might require fast and complex search. Indexes on many columns

- Audits have lot of inserts; almost no update; few reads. Read, search don't requires complex search (e.g. you only consult audits and sort them by date) and indexes on many columns.

So with increased load and data size you will probably need to split the data and optimize tables for your use cases.

Comment: yes, that make sense. Scalability is one issue which is causing me concerns as this data can grow quickly.